# Embed RTMP Stream

Tags: embed, rtmp, live-streaming

I need a complete crash course on this. I have Adobe Media Server running. Streaming a live feed from a camera to it. I can use the wowza test page http://www.wowza.com/resources/3.5.0/examples/LiveVideoStreaming/FlashRTMPPlayer/player.html to view the stream with:

rtmp://192.81.63.10/live

livestream

This is on a public and as long as I have it running anyone can test it.
This is where I am stuck. I am completely lost at this point. From what I've seen I need to make a .swf file, but can't figure out how to get that working either and my Adobe Flash Builder doesn't seem to want to load. What do I do next to get this on a webpage of my own?

I tried this:

```
<embed width="1280" height="720" src="http://www.focusonthefamily.com/family/JWPlayer/mediaplayer.swf" flashvars="allowfullscreen=true&allowscriptaccess=always&autostart=true&shownavigation=true&enablejs=true&volume=50&file=20100809-wait-no-more-v1.mp4&streamer=rtmp://192.81.63.10/live/livestream/" />
```

But, it just spins nonstop.

Comment: To the people that hit the negative button: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction while you took the time to press it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer:

```
<embed width="1280" height="720" src="http://www.focusonthefamily.com/family/JWPlayer/mediaplayer.swf" flashvars="allowfullscreen=true&allowscriptaccess=always&autostart=true&shownavigation=true&enablejs=true&volume=50&file=livestream&streamer=rtmp://192.81.63.10/live" />
```

Or u could just download jwplayer and use that for the source. This is a better option since learning a bit more on the subject after posting this the first day I was trying and couldn't find an answer. Btw thanks to the people this downvoting this old question and answer.

Comment: who is "focusonthefamily", why aren't they serving this widget over ssl, and why should anyone trust them?

Comment: This was useful to me because it helped me understand how things were working for the webcam I was trying to set up. Just now I tried your link and it worked which is a start for me to look into setting up jwplayer. THanks for the input! @Shane Becker

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write your own player? I know that you have Flash Builder so you can edit your own without problem, no? It also generates the correct html files.

If you want a working sample try this one : http://raspi.monaserver.ovh/MonaClients/VideoPlayer/
The sources are available on github here : https://github.com/MonaSolutions/MonaClients/tree/master/VideoPlayer